io_uring recvmsg_multishot : how is msghdr not overwritten?
My understanding is that using this API, the kernel will continuously fill the CQ with messages until it can't (out of buffers, socket closed, etc).
But each completion fills in the single msghdr provided to the multishot setup call. So if my UDP socket receives 4 udp packets from 4 different hosts while my app is busy : arn't all 4 going to override the single msghdr pointer?
